# Finding the maximal area ellipse in a closed area

Tags: conic-sections, nonlinear-optimization

The task is the following: Find the ellipse with maximal area.

The center of the ellipse is given. Several inequalities are also given, and all of the ellipse's points must satisfy all of the inequalities. So basically I need to find the maximal area ellipse which is in the area enclosed by the inequalities. Here is a picture for illustration: https://ibb.co/LS93208

In my example the center is (Cx,Cy)=(1,1), and the inequalities are the following:

1. y <= 0.5x + 4
2. y >= (1/3)x - 3
3. y >= -0.5x - 4
4. y <= -0.25x + 4

Any idea how can you solve this? I've tried creating an optimization model where the objective function is the area(width*height) and the three decision variables are width(x2),height(x3),rotation angle(x1) - these 3 determine the ellipse -, but I can't seem to write up the right constraints. I share the model I created, but it is probably wrong. The objective function is x2*x3, you have to maximize it.

https://ibb.co/RSLQ05L

The first 2 equations on the picture is the general ellipse equation, followed by the 4 inequalities(alpha between 0 and 2pi). Then I substituted x(alpha) and y(alpha) into the inequalities(I don't know if it's a right move), and moved everything to left side so the right side is 0. The result is:

https://ibb.co/TbcM2dM

I can't manage to solve this optimization problem in matlab, so I'm on a wrong track probably and you don't solve this task as an optimization problem.

Comment: Is this to be done just once for this quadrilateral or do you need a programmatic solution? This solves your problem if the center is not prescribed http://chrisjones.id.au/Ellipses/ellipse.html , I think your problem is harder.

Comment: I need a programmatic solution, and I will need to extend this to higher dimensions later. I just created this example for illustration. I will check your link, maybe it helps.

Comment: I suspect this interesting question is hard. I would start by trying to solve answer it for the unit square when the center is an arbitrary point there. Perhaps numerical methods finding each parameter in turn will work. Start with the largest circle, then stretch it, then rotate.

Comment: First I created an algorithm like that, then I had an idea to create an optimization model. Maybe I will try to implement the algorithm and see how it works if no one has an idea to make my model work.

Comment: Good luck. https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=largest+ellipse+quadrilateral&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8  http://faculty.mae.carleton.ca/John_Hayes/Papers/CCToMM_MJDH_MaxEllipse_RevF.pdf

Comment: A first operation is to make a change of coordinates taking the ellipse centre as the origin, giving inequations $Y \geq 0.5x+3.5, Y \leq  \frac13X-11/3, $ etc.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker : very good reference.

Comment: I think that you’ve gotten the sense of all of those inequalities backwards. The required center point $(1,1)$ doesn’t satisfy any of them.

Comment: Yes, the original task says that the ellipse must not contain any point that satisfies any of those inequalities, I just copied from there and forgot to change the inequality signs when writing the question. But I worked with the correct inequalities, you can see on the first picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone interested, my optimization model was correct and could be solved in matlab(fseminf function), also can be generalized to higher dimension